# Can't load Mxd file in MapControl?

Tags: arcobjects, mapcontrol

I used below codes to save IMap into byte[] (to store in my database), but I can't load it again, are there anyone know what's wrong ?

```
public byte[] SaveMap(AxPageLayoutControl pageLayOut)
{
    IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = pageLayOut.GraphicsContainer;
    graphicsContainer.Reset();
    IElement pElement = graphicsContainer.Next();
    while (pElement != null)
    {
           if (pElement is IMapFrame)
           {
               IMapDocument mapDocument = new MapDocumentClass();
               if (File.Exists(@"D:\test.mxd")) 
                        File.Delete (@"D:\test.mxd");

               mapDocument.New(@"D:\test.mxd");
               mapDocument.ReplaceContents((IMxdContents)pageLayoutTo2_3.ActiveView.FocusMap);
               mapDocument.Save(true, true);

               System.IO.FileStream objFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"D:\test.mxd", FileMode.Open);
               byte[] result = new byte[objFileStream.Length];
               objFileStream.Read(result, 0, (int)objFileStream.Length);

               return result;
            }
            pElement = graphicsContainer.Next();
      }
}

public void LoadMap(AxPageLayoutControl pageLayOut, byte[] result)
{
    IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = pageLayoutTo2_3.GraphicsContainer;
    graphicsContainer.Reset();
    IElement pElement = graphicsContainer.Next();
    while (pElement != null)
    {
           if (pElement is IMapFrame)
           {

               System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"D:\test.mxd", FileMode.Append);
               oFileStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);

               IMapControl2 map = new MapControlClass();
               map.LoadMxFile(@"D:\test.mxd", Type.Missing, Type.Missing );

               IMapFrame frame = new MapFrameClass();
               frame.Map = map.Map;
               pElement = (IElement)frame;

               pageLayOut.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);

               return;
            }
            pElement = graphicsContainer.Next();
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using IMapDocument.Open to get the IMap in Loadmap?  Also, did you try adding IMapDocument.Close after saving?

Answer (score 1):

You seem going to serialize and deserialize Map object. The class which implement IPersistStream interface can serialize and deserialize to byte array, string or text file. Here's a sample code.

```
//serialize Map object to byte array
IMap pMap = axMapControl1.Map;
IXMLStream pXMLStream = new XMLStreamClass();
IObjectStream pObjStream = new ObjectStreamClass();
pObjStream.Stream = pXMLStream as IStream;
pObjStream.SaveObject(pMap);
byte[] bytes = pXMLStream.SaveToBytes();

...

//deserialize byte array to Map object
IXMLStream pXMLStream = new XMLStreamClass();
pXMLStream.LoadFromBytes(ref bytes);
IObjectStream pObjStream = new ObjectStreamClass();
pObjStream.Stream = pXMLStream as IStream;
Guid guid = typeof(IMap).GUID;
IMap pMap = pObjStream.LoadObject(ref guid, null) as IMap;
axMapControl1.Map = pMap;
```

Comment: Thanks Darksanta. I have ever tried your way, but I am want to use another way. I resoved this problem